# vagrant ssh fail when using synced_folder

Tags: vagrant

I want to mount a local directory relative to my vagrant file inside the vm. However, when I do that,

> vagrant ssh

No longer works -- private key fails. I am not sure why ssh suddenly fails.
help? (if it matters: I am trying to mount the directory my Java artifacts compile to).

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64-bit as our operating system
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Configurate the virtual machine to use 2GB of RAM
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    vb.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder "target/", "/home/vagrant"

end
```

Comment: can you explain further ? which `sync_folder` do you add in your Vagrantfile so it fails and what is the error message (potentially run with --debug turn on and just paste the necessary information before the error)

Comment: Ahhh, I pasted the wrong snippet. Let me edit

Comment: but do you have a .ssh/ directory in your host target directory with the ssh key ? I would not recommend mounting directly on the /home directory

Comment: I have, on my local host, a. ssh directory in my home. If I don't try to sync vagrant picks that up. I need to be able to login and have host files available

Comment: on your host you have your own .ssh directory which is fine, but in the VM your home user's directory (so /home/vagrant) would need to have the .ssh directory to contain the authorized key. thing is vagrant would create this when vagrant ssh but as right after that it removes everything because you sync on /home/vagrant it gets removed and cannot authenticate you. so either you include in your host target/ directory so it exists when you sync or better you do not sync on the /home/vagrant directory

Comment: @FrédéricHenri your answer was correct. Change it to an actual answer and I will give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you try to sync directly on `/home/vagrant` in the VM, you need to make sure your `target` directory contains a `.ssh` folder with the `authorized_keys`

When you `vagrant up` the VM, vagrant will ssh and create this directory for you but when going through the sync_folder part, it will replace all the content from `/home/vagrant` with your host `target/` so loosing what it did create before.

If you really really want to sync on `/home/vagrant` what you could do is run first without the sync, copy all files that have been created (.ssh/, .bash ...) into your target directory and then you should be able to rerun with the sync on /home/vagrant. (Note: I did not try that and honestly would not recommend to sync on /home/vagrant directly as if you install other soft from provisioning or other, you might run into issues later)